# How to deserialize CommandResult?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, nosql

I am using 10Gen offical c# driver and i am directly using RunCommand method and get CommandResult but i am not able to deserialize.

```
var commandResult = db.RunCommand(command);

list<Post> posts =  ??// how to deserialize to posts collection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide some more information? What command are you running?

Perhaps you just want to query the posts collection, in which case you should use the FindAll method instead:

```
var server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost/?safe=true");
var database = server["test"];
var collection = database.GetCollection<Post>("posts");

var posts = collection.FindAll().ToList();
```

[Edit]

Based on your comment below that you are using the aggregation framework (which is not yet released but is available on the master development branch) I can provide some additional information.

The C# driver does not yet have support for the new aggregation framework, but since it is based on commands you can use it even before the driver officially supports it. The key is understanding that the CommandResult exposes the raw BSON document returned via the Response property and then knowing how to pick apart the response. For example:

```
var commandResult = collection.RunCommand(aggregationCommand);
var response = commandResult.Response;
foreach (BsonDocument result in response["results"].AsBsonArray)
{
    // process result
}
```

In the above loop the result variable is of type BsonDocument. Assuming that this BsonDocument is a valid serialization of an instance of Post, you could deserialize it like this:

```
var post = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Post>(result);
```

Comment: I am actualy execute new aggregation framework pipeline commands so i am not able to use other methods.